# How can I use scope to search in WebStorm but still exclude node_modules?

Tags: webstorm

I am using WebStorm 2018.2.6

I want to be able to exclude a few folders and file extensions from my searches (when using 'Find in Path').  I set up some scopes to do this, but when I use them, it includes node_modules.

Node_modules are marked as excluded in the Project window.  Node_modules is not selectable in the scopes builder.  I have typed in the path as I know it but the search still does not exclude it.

If I select 'In Project' instead of 'Scope' when searching, it works as desired but it doesn't allow me to exclude other files I'd like to exclude.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Add condition for `node_modules` folder manually? E.g. Add some another folder on the same level, then just edit the rule by changing that folder to a desired one...

Comment: Yup, I had tried that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `node_modules` are only partially excluded - direct dependencies listed in `package.json` are added to *JavaScript libraries* and thus included.

To exclude `node_modules` completely, use *In Project* scope for searching. JavaScript libraries are only included when using *Directory* scope with corresponding folder selected, or when using custom scope with explicit filters. Note that excluding libraries from custom scope is a bit tricky... To make it work, you need to prefix your scope pattern with `file[your_project_name]:*/&&` to overwrite the default scope - see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145142#comment=27-1156171 for explanation

Related feature request: [IDEA-103560](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-103560)

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Project window (Alt +1)
2. right click 'node_modules' folder, click 'Mark Directory As' , click 'Cancel Exclusion'
3. In Scope, you can see the node_modules folder.
4. wait for IDE to index file, and then search